# Printing with delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I am facing some difficulties while printing, when I print my reports to physical printer the texts are perfectly centred but when I print the same report to PDF printer (e.g. cutePDF) or XPS document writer the left margin becomes 0. Meanwhile when I am trying to adjust the margin it works fine in PDF and XPS but the physical printing prints the pages with some extra left margin. I am not able to find out this difference also I tried to  set the margin only for non-physical printing but could not able to do this.
It would be great if it will possible to set the marige according to printer selection e.g. if I will select PDF printer or XPS writer the margin gets changed. I am using Printer.canvas.textout(), procedure to print the text.

Can anybody please help me for this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's almost impossible for anyone to help you with your problem, because you posted no code. If we can't see how you're trying to print, we can't possibly see what you're doing wrong. Please remember we can't see your screen from here, and so 100% of the information we have is what you provide in your question. Please edit your post and provide relevant code (you might also try adding some paragraph breaks in your question to make it more readable while you're at it). In order for us to help you with your problem, you have to help us understand it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

Some points which are worth be highligted:

- From the Windows (and Delphi's `TPrinter.Canvas`) POV, there is **no** such concept as *margins* during drawing: the whole paper size is available to the canvas - for instance, X=0 will point to the absolute leftmost part of the paper;
- There are so called "hardware margins" or "physical margins", depending on the printer capability: this is the non printable area around the paper; that is, if you draw something in this area, it won't be painted - these margins depend on the technology and model of printer used, and in some cases, it is possible to retrieve those "margins" values from the printer driver via [`GetDeviceCaps` API calls](http://delphi-kb.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-control-print-margins-when.html);
- But, from my experiment, do not trust those "physical margins" as retrieved by the printer driver - it is better (and more esthetical) to use some software defined margins, and let your user change it if necessary (like the "Page layout" options of MS Word);
- PDF printers usually are virtual printers, so they do not have any "physical margin";
- When you print a PDF document, Acrobat Reader is able to "fit" the page content to the "physical margins" of the physical printer.

So here are some possible solutions:

- From Acrobat Reader, if your PDF has no margin, click on Print, then select "Fit to Printable Area" in the "Page Handling / Page Scaling" option - I guess you have "None " as settings here so the result is truncated by the printer;
- From your Delphi application, set some "logical" margins (e.g. 1 cm around your paper) when drawing your report - that is, do not start at X=0 and Y=0, but with some offsets, and let the width and height of your drawing area be smaller (see for instance how is implemented our Open Source [Report engine](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/06/30/Making-report-from-code));
- From your Delphi application, if you use a Report component, there should be some properties to set the margins.

See [this article](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Printing/index.html) about general printing using Delphi (some info is old, but most is still accurate), or set up properly your report engine.

Comment: thanks a lot for such a nice explanation. I think what you sugested to have some "logical" margin all around the pages would be good.

Comment: In Delphi XE2 (at least) `Printer.PageWidth` is equal to `GetDeviceCaps(DC, HorzRes)` which is the width of the *printable* region of the page, i.e. less than the physical width of the paper.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `TextOut` (and not `DrawText`) you have the x and y coordinate where you are going to put the string(s) you need to print. You can follow the calculations in the debugger (or log them if the application runs without a debugger present). Perhaps something goes wrong in determining the coordinates (eg `TextExtend` fails to measure the text before centering, eg the resolution is different from what you expect, you get the Printer Canvas with a transformation so the coordinates are not 1:1 with the pixels.

If you are unsure about the coordinates / font issues: try drawing some boxes at expected coordinates so you can leave all font related errors out of the equation. If they exhibit the same problems it's a coordinate problem, if not it's font problem somehow.

As Ken said, we cannot know anything more if you do not show the code... so many possibilities..

Comment: If you'd hold your answer until it's proper question, it would be better (and might get you upvotes). Trying to answer a non-question just encourages people not to edit and improve it. (Not downvoting your answer, but not upvoting either.) The fact that the asker can follow the calculations in the debugger is **guessing** that the user might actually be doing some kind of calculations based on specific output, which it appears they're not. Waiting for code and information means you have something to go on when answering. :)

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I will try to post some sample code

Comment: @Ken: I disagree with you. Yes more information and better yet source code would work better but he did say he tried to center texts drawn with textout. So I was not GUESSING. If you would have read the quetsion carefully you would see it contains far more information you apparently noticed in the first place.

Comment: No problem. Trying to help both you and the original poster, but apparently you took offense. My apologies. (But you were GUESSING (shouting yours, not mine), because the OP never said there were calculations being done or what data/algorithm was being used; Dinesh simply said things worked on one surface and not the other when using `TextOut`."When I ride my bike, sometimes it stops quickly and other times it takes a while." How fast was the bike going? When it stops fast, is it because you squeezed the brake harder or because you hit a tree? The details make a difference. Nice guess, though.

Comment: @Ken: point taken. Also my apologies for overreacting a bit, thank you for reacting in such a friendly manner. And now onto the subject: if he calls textout, he uses the canvas himself, textout only has x,y and no rect, so if he needs to center a text he needs to calculate the correct coordinates based upon the dimensions. Thus we have a call to textout, we have a calculation he does himself and whatever is the proverbial tree of brake is guessing; did the calculation go wrong, was the calculation based upon the wrong dimensions, are the coordinates different ect etc that's guessing al right.

Comment: @Ritsaert, no problems. :) And your last comment was what I was trying to say - until the OP comes back and provides more details and some code to see where the problem is, the question is really hard to answer. (And you'll note that the poster hasn't done so.) :)